# Desvincular un gráfico dinámico de la tabla

Tags: excel

He creado una tabla dinámica en Excel para hacer diferentes combinaciones entre sus variables. El objetivo final es hacer un gráfico con cada una de las combinaciones para que la explotación de datos sea visualmente más atractiva.

Mi problema es que cuando selecciono una nueva combinación de variables el gráfico que había hecho anteriormente se modifica en base a la nueva selección de manera que no soy capaz de guardar dos gráficos diferentes en el mismo documento de excel. Me están metiendo prisa en el trabajo y me he atascado aquí!

Pd.: no soy ni programadora ni informática ni tengo grandes conocimientos al respecto. Simplemente nunca se me ha dado mal trastear y así voy aprendiendo.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme y muchas gracias de antemano! =)

Answer (score 1):

En Excel existen varios tipos de gráficos, los normales y los dinámicos. Estos últimos están vinculados siempre a una tabla dinámica, por lo tanto si cambias la configuración de la tabla dinámica cambias el gráfico.

Puedes solucionarlo de varias formas. La solución te la va a dar siempre el origen de tus datos.

- **Datos no agrupados**: Creando varios gráficos dinámicos y por lo tanto varias gráficas dinámicas.
- **Datos agrupados**: Creando gráficos seleccionando como origen una tabla normal en vez de una tabla dinámica.

Sería interesante saber que versión de Excel tienes ya que los menús y la forma de crearlos son diferentes. Si tienes la versión 2016 y ya que indicas que tienes poca experiencia, te recomiendo una opción muy chula para crear gráficos dinámicos. Selecciona cualquier posición de la tabla que quieras resumir. Ves al menú insertar, "Gráficos recomendados".
Esta opción te genera una nueva pestaña con la tabla y el gráfico dinámicos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último y si quieres mostrar varios gráficos en una pestaña. Te recomiendo que crees una pestaña para mostrar información gráfica y muevas los que te gusten a la misma. Así queda más chulo ;-)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.